# jquery list confusion

Tags: jquery

I'm a new to the jQuery world and I'm having a problem that I just can't solve.  I have an unordered list with multiple li's.  I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks a row, the bg color on the row changes.  And when another row is click, that row's bg color changes and the previous on goes back to the default color.  This is my code so far:

```
$('.allVideos ul li').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('background','#c7f1f2');
}, function(){
   $(":not($(this))").css('background','');
});
```

Unfortunately it isn't working as planned.  Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you are using 'hover' function here. You should use click

Comment: @Jayantha Not if he wants it to happen on a hover.

Comment: yes but he said that `when the user clicks a row`

Comment: Oh, so he did--weird to use hover then ;)

Comment: Sorry...was going to say that the row changes one color on hover then another color on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`not` filter](http://api.jquery.com/not/), not the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#c7f1f2');
    $('li').not(this).css('background-color', '');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZUk88/

When you say `li:not($(this))` then you're trying to select all `<li>` elements that aren't `<$(this)>` elements and that doesn't make sense; similarly for `li:not(this)`.

You could also remove the background color from all the list items and then add it to the one you want:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#c7f1f2');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/L6ZNz/

Also, your question talks about clicking but your code talks about hovering.

---

If you have colors already attached to your `<li>` elements and you want to restore those colors when someone clicks another `<li>`, then you should just add and remove a CSS class to change the color. A bit of CSS:

```
.hilight {
    background-color: #c7f1f2 !important;
}
```

and some jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.hilight').removeClass('hilight');
    $(this).addClass('hilight');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZJpNa/

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone.  I was able to fix my problem based on the input I received here.

Answer (score 3):

this will work ,

```
$('.allVideos ul li').click(function(){

   $(".allVideos ul li").not($(this)).css('background','');
   $(this).css('background','#c7f1f2');
});
```

Comment: its perfect but can u please update the same by not setting all the li's to same background colr, if all the li have different background.